# how can i get a list of Azure VMS with operating system installed using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-vm

I run the following command and get a list for one vm which details what operating system is installed, however, is there a way I can do this for all VMS in a subscription rather than one by one and output it to a csv file? I need to know which version of windows is installed on all vms

```
az vm show -g $vmresourcegroup -n $vmname --query '[name, storageProfile.imageReference]'
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the below script you can pull the list of virtual machines under a particular subscription with VirtualMachineName, Operating system & their SKU names

```html
az login

$result = az vm list --subscription <subscriptionName> `
 --query "[].[name,storageProfile.imageReference.offer,storageProfile.imageReference.sku]" 
$json = $result | ConvertFrom-Json

$json | % {
$item = New-Object PSCustomObject
$item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "vmName" -NotePropertyValue $_.SyncRoot[0]
$item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Os" -NotePropertyValue $_.SyncRoot[1]
$item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "sku" -NotePropertyValue $_.SyncRoot[2]

$item | Export-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\9.csv  -NoTypeInformation  -Append
}
```

[image]

Comment: @itye1970 - if the above answer provided was helpful ? If so could you please accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part of your question:

`az vm list` will return all vms in the current subscription. As it returns an array of vms, you also need to adjust your JMESPATH query accordingly:

```
az vm list --query '[].[name, storageProfile.imageReference]'
```

Regarding the second part of your question:

In order to get csv output you will need to flatten the output first, as "imageReference" has several subproperties.

I get from the tags in your question that you are running az cli in PowerShell:

```
 az vm list -o json | 
  ConvertFrom-Json | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty StorageProfile -Property Name | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty ImageReference -Property Name |
  ConvertTo-Csv
```

Comment: that works but if vms are deallocated it does not list the os ?

Comment: I just tried the command against two deallocated vms. All ImageReference properties are shown.

Comment: i get this when running the above command : Select-Object : Property "storageProfile" cannot be found.
At line:3 char:3
+   Select-Object -ExpandProperty storageProfile -Property Name |
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (               ...               :PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException