# azure cli or KQL query to get the list of VMs enabled with VMinsights

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

need to know what are the services / programs / extensions installed on a VM when VM insights is enabled for an Azure VM

Answer (score 2):

**To get the list of extensions installed on particular Azure VM**, Make use of below Azure CLI command:

```
 Get-AzVM -Name "your_vm_name" -ResourceGroup "your_resource_group_name" | Select -ExpandProperty Extensions | Select Name
```

[image: image1]

- **To get list of extensions installed on all your Azure VMs**, Make use of below Kusto script if helpful:

```
Resources
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| extend
    JoinID = toupper(id),
    OSName = tostring(properties.osProfile.computerName),
    OSType = tostring(properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType),
    VMSize = tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize)
| join kind=leftouter(
    Resources
    | where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/extensions'
    | extend
        VMId = toupper(substring(id, 0, indexof(id, '/extensions'))),
        ExtensionName = name
) on $left.JoinID == $right.VMId
| summarize Extensions = make_list(ExtensionName) by id, OSName, OSType, VMSize
| order by tolower(OSName) asc
```

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Advanced query samples - Azure Resource Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/advanced?tabs=azure-cli#join-vmextension)

[powershell - how can i get a list of Azure VMS with operating system installed using Azure CLI? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68284948/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-azure-vms-with-operating-system-installed-using-azure-cl?rq=1)